# JavaScript Having trouble deleting dynamically created iframe

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm not able to remove pre-created iframes in a call to a function. I have set visibility:visible so I can see what's going on, and newly created iframes are stacking up next to each other with each new call to the function.

BTW, "iframe" really is the id in the dynamically created iframe. So `document.getElementById('iframe')` is correct.

Code:

```
    if( document.getElementById(iframe) ){
        var e = document.getElementById("iframe");
        e.removeChild(document.getElementById("iframe"));
    }
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("id","iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("class","iframe");
    document.getElementById("output").appendChild(iframe);
    $("#iframe").attr("display","block");
    $("#iframe").attr("src",url);
```

... I have also tried :

```
if( typeof document.getElementById(iframe) !== "undefined" ){
    var e = document.getElementById("iframe");
    e.removeChild(document.getElementById("iframe")); // e is null error here
}
```

... but this results in a "e is null error
...and

```
if( ! typeof document.getElementById(iframe) == "undefined" ){
    var e = document.getElementById("iframe");
    e.removeChild(document.getElementById("iframe"));
}
```

...no error, but the iframe doesn't get removed, either.

Comment: Where is your `iframe` variable set. `getElementById` expects a string but then you are setting that same variable to a dom element

Comment: What are all these `getElementById` calls?

Comment: you seem to mix `"iframe"` and `iframe` indiscriminately in your code, almost as if you think the browser should "know what you mean" rather than expecting you to write coherent and consistent code

Comment: @Daniel_L The iframe element is right there in my example, where it says `var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");`

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm setting an element id = "iframe", and I'm calling an element with an id="iframe". What's wrong with that?

Comment: *So document.getElementById('iframe') is correct* ... however `document.getElementById(iframe)` is not

Comment: First line of code you use `iframe` where you should be using `"iframe"` - and scattered in your code is multiple instances of this error

Comment: I hope it was a positive explosion

Comment: Yep, the problem was `getElementById(iframe)` instead of `getElementById('iframe')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
if( document.getElementById(iframe) ){
    var e = document.getElementById("iframe");
    e.removeChild(document.getElementById("iframe"));
}
```

Should be changed to this:

```
if( document.getElementById("iframe") ){
    document.getElementById("iframe").remove();
}
```